# Sharing different content based on selected activity - UIActivityController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

Currently I am sending a Image and a text whenever the user wants to share the image using `UIActivityController`.
This works fine on email and gmail , but its gets messed up for whatsapp or Skype(Only the text is sent).
So what I would like to do is share image url and text if the user selects activity as whatsapp or Skype. Is this possible?

I searched for this problem , and found that you should sub class `UIActivityItemProvider` and implement the methods of `UIActivityItemSource` which I did, but I am unable to get callbacks for the implemented methods.

I have implemented these methods 
`activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:` and `activityViewController:itemForActivityType:`
but I don't receive a callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make a subclass of `UIActivityItemProvider` and override `item` property to give your custom `activity items`, i.e.

```
class CustomActivityItemProvider: UIActivityItemProvider
{
    override var item: Any{
        switch self.activityType!
        {
        case UIActivityType.postToFacebook:
            return "Hello"
        default:
            return "Whatever"
        }
    }
}
```

Using it:

```
let activityItem = CustomActivityItemProvider(placeholderItem: "")
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityItem], applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Also, you can customize only those `UIActivityType`, that are exposed by `Apple` for use by developers. For `UIActivityTypes` refer to: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivitytype

Comment: Perfect and "swift" answer . So  apparently I don't need to override the protocol methods if I want pass custom data based on the activity type.

Comment: Sure..Enjoy..:)

Comment: What exactly do you want to change?